# Streaming Tweet Search TweetSharp

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I am new to Tweet Sharp and C# in general. I was wondering how would i go about streaming live tweets of a particular hash tag.

I have been using such methods as ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline that return a number of tweets of my user home page however they it is not live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used TweetSharp in a long while, and can't remember how to stream certain hash tags, but to return the user stream you can experiment with this method:

```
    public void StreamFromUser()
    {
        var block = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        var service = GetAuthenticatedService();

        service.StreamUser((streamEvent, response) =>
        {
            if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamEnd)
            {
                block.Set();
            }

            if (response.StatusCode == 0)
            {
                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamFriends)
                {
                    var friends = (TwitterUserStreamFriends)streamEvent;
                }

                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamEvent)
                {
                    var @event = (TwitterUserStreamEvent)streamEvent;
                }

                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamStatus)
                {
                    var tweet = ((TwitterUserStreamStatus)streamEvent).Status;
                }

                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDirectMessage)
                {
                    var dm = ((TwitterUserStreamDirectMessage)streamEvent).DirectMessage;
                }

                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDeleteStatus)
                {
                    var deleted = (TwitterUserStreamDeleteStatus)streamEvent;
                }

                if (streamEvent is TwitterUserStreamDeleteDirectMessage)
                {
                    var deleted = (TwitterUserStreamDeleteDirectMessage)streamEvent;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.Ignore("Stream responsed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            }
        });

        block.WaitOne();
        service.CancelStreaming();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, I tried to implement this however it just freezes my code.

Comment: Thats because the streaming function runs on a separate thread, you need to return to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Tweet Sharp has been discontinued. However, I have heard good things about linqtotwitter if you need a 3rd party library https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/